# Langchain: Why does langchain agent return the action input instead of running it?

Tags: python, langchain

I'm working with a Langchain agent.

I'm running into a phenomenon: After small talk with the chatbot where the user provides it with parameters to executes a function (set as a tool), instead of running the function, it returns to the user the action input instead.

Any ideas why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Here is the agent type I am running:

```
    agent_executor = initialize_agent(
        tools, 
        llm, 
        agent=AgentType.STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, 
        verbose=True, 
        memory=memory, 
        return_intermediate_steps=False,
        agent_kwargs = {
            'prefix': Prompt_Prefix, 
            "memory_prompts": [chat_history],
            "input_variables": ["input", "agent_scratchpad", "chat_history"]
        }
    )
```

Comment: Please provide a code explaining the problem

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot provide a code. But I can explain in greater detail: My langchain agent is returning its thoughts to the user instead of using them to select the right tool. Further it is returning the action input instead of using it to run my custom function.

Comment: Can you reproduce error in simple example?

Comment: Any updates on this? I have the same problem when I use gpt-3.5-turbo instead of gpt-4

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Hi All,

I changed my AgentType from AgentType.STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION to AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS. I had to shorten the tool description to accommodate this change. After making this change, the chatbot became much more stable. It no longer returned the action input and operated much more smoothly. This was a game-changer, and I highly recommend this change to the agent type.

Answer (score -1):

from what I am able to understand about Langchain agents and also about your question is :

1. you are requesting for an action to be performed using an LLM like OpenAI using Langchain Agents sitting in between.

> From my understanding, when we request for an action to be performed
> using LangChain agents we receive a JSON response which is then passed
> to the website as an event.

**For example:** if we ask to change the theme of a website to dark,
LangChain will send a response with JSON data directing to change the theme.

**We need to pass this response as an event to our webpage in order to perform this action.**
Here is a diagrammatical  representation of this process.
[image]

Hope I was able to help :).